# Iterating through a linked list erases data

Tags: c, linked-list, iteration

I wrote a program to store in two lists data of a bank and its clients and when asked print all the account info regarding a given client, note that a single could have multiple accounts in multiple banks. Storing was OK and also the first iteration to search an account name, but then the list of clients is erased...
 What am I doing wrong?
These are the input files:

in1.txt

```
sanpaolo rome dddd aaaaaa in2.txt

unicredit rome dddd aaaaaa in3.txt
```

in2.txt

```
rossi mario xxxxx 1000
rossi luigi zzzzz 2000
scipio hannibal aaads 10
toad peach ssss 1000
toad peach ddwd 100000
rossi mario 222x2 100000
```

in3.txt

```
rossi mario aaaaxx 1000
toad princess ccczzz 2000
panerai watch xxxads 10
pavlov dog saaasss 1000
froid freud ddcwd 100000
froid freud 222x2 100000
```

This is a sample of the output

```
enter name to search end to terminate:
toad
unicredit rome dddd aaaaaa
 toad princess ccczzz 2000
 sanpaolo rome dddd aaaaaa
 toad peach ddwd    100000
 toad peach ssss 1000
 enter name to search end to terminate:
 froid
 unicredit rome dddd aaaaaa
 -
 sanpaolo rome dddd aaaaaa
 -
```

And here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 50

struct bank {
    char name[LEN];
    char branch[LEN];
    char abi[LEN];
    char cab[LEN];
    struct bank *next;
    struct client *link;
};

struct client {
    char lastname[LEN];
    char firstname[LEN];
    char iban[LEN];
    long int deposit;
    struct client *next;
};

void cleanUp(struct bank *headP, struct client *headP2);
static void printclientinfo(struct client *client);
static void printbankinfo(struct bank *bank);
static void searchperson(struct bank *bank, char *name);
struct bank *pushbank(struct bank *bank,char *tname, char *tbranch,
                      char *tabi, char *tcab, char *filename);
struct client *pushclient(struct client *client, char *last, char *first,
                          char *iban, long int deposit);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char name[LEN], branch[LEN], abi[LEN], cab[LEN], filename[LEN], string[LEN];
    struct bank *mybank = NULL, *t = NULL;
    FILE *in1;
    in1 = fopen("in1.txt", "r");
    while (fscanf(in1,"%s %s %s %s %s", name, branch, abi, cab, filename) != EOF) {
        mybank = pushbank(mybank, name, branch, abi, cab, filename);
    }
    while (1 == 1) {
        t = mybank;

        printf("enter name to search \t end to terminate:\n");
        scanf("%s", string);
        if (strcmp(string, "end") == 0) {
            fclose(in1);
            cleanUp(mybank, mybank->link);
            return 0;
        } else {
            searchperson(t, string);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void cleanUp(struct bank *headP, struct client *headP2) {
    struct bank *tmpP, *l_Next;
    struct client *tmpP2, *l_Next2;

    tmpP = headP;
    tmpP2 = headP2;
    while (tmpP != NULL) {
        l_Next = tmpP->next;
        free(tmpP->link);
        free(tmpP->next);
        tmpP = l_Next;
    }
    while (tmpP2 != NULL) {
        l_Next2 = tmpP2->next;
        free(tmpP2->next);
        tmpP2 = l_Next2;
    }

    free(tmpP);
    free(tmpP2);

    headP = NULL;
    headP2 = NULL;
    return;
}

static void printbankinfo(struct bank *bank) {
    struct bank *t = NULL;
    t = bank;
    printf("%s %s %s %s\n", t->name,t->branch, t->abi, t->cab);
}

static void printclientinfo(struct client *client) {
    struct client *t = NULL;
    t = client;
    printf("\t%s %s %s %ld\n", t->lastname, t->firstname, t->iban, t->deposit);
}

static void searchperson(struct bank *bank, char *name) {
    int flag = 0;

    while (bank != NULL) {
        printbankinfo(bank);
        flag = 0;
        while (bank->link != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(bank->link->lastname, name) == 0) {
                printclientinfo(bank->link);
                flag = 1;
            }
            bank->link = bank->link->next;
        }
        if (flag == 0) printf("-\n");
        bank = bank->next;
    }
}

struct bank *pushbank(struct bank *bank, char *tname, char *tbranch,
                      char *tabi, char *tcab, char *filename) {
    struct bank *newptr = NULL;
    char last[LEN], first[LEN], iban[LEN];
    long int deposit;
    FILE *in;
    in = fopen(filename, "r");
    newptr = malloc(sizeof(struct bank));
    strcpy(newptr->name, tname);
    strcpy(newptr->branch, tbranch);
    strcpy(newptr->abi, tabi);
    strcpy(newptr->cab, tcab);
    newptr->link = NULL;
    while (fscanf(in, "%s %s %s %ld", last, first, iban, &deposit) != EOF) {
        newptr->link = pushclient(newptr->link, last, first, iban, deposit);
    }
    newptr->next = bank;
    return newptr;
}

struct client *pushclient(struct client *client, char *last, char *first,
                          char *iban, long int deposit) {
    struct client *newptr = NULL;
    newptr = malloc(sizeof(struct client));
    strcpy(newptr->lastname, last);
    strcpy(newptr->firstname, first);
    strcpy(newptr->iban, iban);
    newptr->deposit = deposit;
    newptr->next = client;
    return newptr;
}
```

Comment: Always check that `malloc()` didn;t return `NULL` Also: *add spaces around operators so that the operands are clearly distinguished when you look at them*, you can ignore this advice or take it and improve your code formatting skills.

Comment: What di you find out when you debugged it?

Comment: "but then the list of clients is erased". How did you come to that conclusion? Please tell us the exact sequence of input searches you performed, what the expected result was and what the actual result was.

Comment: @kaylum debugging the program the list of clients was just null <br> I'll paste a copy of the output:<br> enter name to search   end to terminate:<br>
toad<br>
unicredit rome dddd aaaaaa<br>
 toad princess ccczzz 2000<br>
sanpaolo rome dddd aaaaaa<br>
 toad peach ddwd 100000<br>
 toad peach ssss 1000<br>
enter name to search   end to terminate:<br>
froid<br>
unicredit rome dddd aaaaaa<br>
-<br>
sanpaolo rome dddd aaaaaa<br>
-<br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `searchPerson` you do `bank->link=bank->link->next;`. That modifies the original `mybank` client list and corrupts the whole list as you have found.

Instead use a cursor variable so that you don't modify the original list.

```
struct client *current_client = bank->link;
while (current_client != NULL) {
    if ((strcmp(current_client->lastname, name) == 0)){
        printclientinfo(current_client);
        flag=1;
    }
    current_client = curent_client->next;
}
```